# How to make RXTX work with 64 bit apps?

Tags: java, rxtx

I am using this library

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.rxtx</groupId>
    <artifactId>rxtx</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.7</version>
</dependency>
```

And it is working in 32 bit.

Upon running it in 64 bit, I am getting this error:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: PATH HERE\rxtxSerial.dll: Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform thrown while loading gnu.io.RXTXCommDriver
```

If there is , is there an available maven dependency?

Comment: Did you think to search on the web for "64-bit rxtx" before posting? The information is all on the download page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did not find one in maven so I just installed manually.